# Change background color if something is added to cart

Tags: php, jquery

I want to write some code to where that when nothing (0) is added to the cart the icon is a light grey, but when something is added to the cart it changes to red.

```
<span class="cart-item-number">1</span>
```

How would I change the color if the cart is greater than or equal to 1? Would I use JQuery or PHP to do this?

Comment: do you need the code for that

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend jquery to change the color based on value.

The `span` does not have a `change` trigger by default. So when you add something to the cart you will need to trigger `change` manually, like so:

```
$('span').text(v).trigger('change');
```

Then you can listen to the `change` trigger and do what you want:

```
$('span').on('change', function() {
    var v = parseInt($('span').text());
    if (v > 0) {
      $('span').css('background', 'red');
    }else{
      $('span').css('background', 'gray');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input` Event :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".cart-item-number").on("input",function(){

        $value  = parseFloat($(this).text());

        if ($value > 0)
            $(this).css({backgroundColor:"red"});

        else
            $(this).css({backgroundColor:"gray"});
    })

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .cart-item-number {
            width: 50px;
            height: 20px;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="cart-item-number" contenteditable="true">1</span>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".cart-item-number").on("input",function(){

            $value  = parseFloat($(this).text());

            if ($value > 0 )
                $(this).css({backgroundColor:"red"});

            else
                $(this).css({backgroundColor:"gray"});
        })

    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Obama Killed Harambe , Check my Answer!

Comment: If I wanted this to apply to all pages where would I put the code?

Comment: I am using Wordpress.